# To which AWS service are mapped these two endpoint URI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I had in my hands these last days two URI belonging to AWS, I am not able to guess which AWS service would generate such URI:
cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
quicksilver.elasticbeanstalk.com

`dig quicksilver.elasticbeanstalk.com` responds with NXDOMAIN so I guess the sysadmin who had a host.example.com CNAME pointing to quicksilver.elasticbeanstalk.com was just a mistake or he had other reasons to do that. Because the correct URI structure for elastic beanstalk would be:
quicksilver.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
There is no way to skip the region part in the URI.

For the first URI, It is a live server:
https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
Which AWS service did generate that URI?
I looked at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html but I am not able to find it.

Update: I still need the answer for the something.elasticbeanstalk.com , I keep seeing URLs with that structure, what I would expect would be:
something.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com, can somebody tell something about it please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quicksilver.elasticbeanstalk.com is from AWS Elastic Beanstalk: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazon.com is from AWS Cognito: https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/

Comment: Thanks, but for the elasticbeanstalk are you sure? I don't see how to create an elastic beanstalk without the region, notice: quicksilver.elasticbeanstalk.com , it does not have the region in the URI!! If it had then that would be easy. Do you know how to create elasticbeanstalk services without URI?

Comment: This behavior changed in 2016 when region became part of the domain for new environments https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/01/aws-elastic-beanstalk-adds-support-for-amazon-route-53-aliasing/